# Configure an eclipse project with gradle

Tags: gradle

I've a single gradle file where I'm applying eclipse plugin:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:1.3.7'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.api:api-all:1.0.0-M30'
    compile 'com.whalin:Memcached-Java-Client:3.0.2'
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.14.3'
    compile 'commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.10'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.1'
}

manifest {
    attributes 'Implementation-Title': '---', 'Implementation-Version': 0.1
}
```

All my source files are under `src/main/java`. When I perform `gradle eclipse` it generates me eclipse artifacts. Then, I import this project using `Import > General > Existing project into workspace`. Nevertheless, my source folders are not set such as source folder into imported project.

Porject structure:

```
workspace
└───project
    └───src
        └───main
            ├───java
            └───resources
```

I'd also like to set other parameters like output folder, java compliance compiler...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[On the official site](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/SourceSetOutput.html) there is a solution of setting the output folder.

```
  apply plugin: 'java'
  sourceSets {
   main {
         //if you truly want to override the defaults:
         output.resourcesDir = 'out/res'
         output.classesDir   = 'out/bin'    
   } 
  }
```

I hope it helps.